# Although I install python-telegram-bot, error of no module named 'telegram'

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I installed telegram packages. But when I try to run the simple example, echobot.py, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "echobot.py", line 8, in <module>
import telegram ImportError: No module named 'telegram'
```

Can anyone help me?

I install using git:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot
```

after this:

```
$ python -i
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import telegram

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'telegram'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not installing it. You are just downloading it.
Run these:

```
cd python-telegram-bot
python setup.py install
```

(stated in readme of the GitHub page)

Alternatively, you can use pip. It's easier to use.

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehmet for the answer, but I try this:
C:\Python27>pip install python-telegram-bot
Requirement already satisfied: python-telegram-bot in c:\users\mahyar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\python_telegram_bot-7.0.1-py3.5.egg
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.16.0 in c:

Comment: Maybe the problem is because of multiple versions of python! Any recommendation?

Comment: Can you try running commands with full path? e.g: C:\Python27\scripts\pip.exe install python-telegram-bot    - pip is under scripts folder

Comment: I uninstalled other pythons, then use this:    $ git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot --recursive
 it means I added --recursive. Hopefully, it worked! Thanks @Mehmet for help, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I solved it this way.[image]

```
pip install telegram
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed when I import telegram.ext, it does not find .ext. The issue was caused by telegram and python-telegram modules being installed. Delete these and install only python-telegram-bot. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall it by `pip uninstall python-telegram-bot`

And after that install it again `pip install python-telegram-bot`

Answer (score 0):

If you have named your python file as **telegram.py** then it will throw this error because the program is calling **ext** function from the file itself.
Try renaming your python file to something else it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two python versions installed.
A quick solution is to idetify which python your code is using. Then go to bin directory where the python is installed. Find the pip binary name inside that using command

> ls -lrt | grep pip

In my cases the name was pip3.6. So use then use that pip name and execute from same directory

> pip3.6 install python-telegram-bot

Long term fix is to add your pip3.6 shortcut in /usr/bin or /usr/loca/bin and install packages using pip3.6 command

Answer (score -1):

Thre problem is in line with smth like

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))
```

in *bot_gae.py*.

You have to point at REAL place, where you've installed python-telegram-bot.

In my case it's *./lib* in project directory.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the python-telegram-bot package is not properly installed in your Python environment. Here's how you can install it using pip, which is the standard package manager for Python:

1. First, make sure you have pip installed. You can check this by running:

```bash
pip --version
```

If you get a version number, then pip is installed. If not, you'll need to install it.

2. Install python-telegram-bot using pip. Run the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

```bash
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

This command will download and install the python-telegram-bot package along with its dependencies.

Once the installation is complete, you should be able to run your echobot.py script without any issues. If you still encounter problems, ensure that you are using the correct Python environment (the one where pip installed the package). You can also try restarting your Python environment or your terminal after the installation.

Answer (score -3):

Install

pip install django-telegrambot

Configure your installation

## settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_telegrambot',
   )

Comment: I dont think this is the library, that questioner wanted to install